# How can I determine the size of a hanging toilet mechanism?

Tags: bathroom, toilet

We would like to install a [hanging toilet](http://www.remodelista.com/posts/10-easy-pieces-wall-mounted-toilets) in an area that is 65cm wide, which is fine for us. However someone told us that the mechanism of a hanging toilet (that's hidden in the back wall) needs at least a width of 70cm. How can I determine if this is true?

Comment: Find the one that you want and download the installation manual.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to be sure your water pressure is adequate (as in high psi). A wall mounted toilet doesn't use a reservoir, but relies on high water pressure for complete flushes.

Comment: Are You sure that wall mounted toilets don't use reservoirs/tanks?... My sister got that kind of toilet and I'm sure that it works with a tank.

Comment: The ones which are meant for public restrooms are like what @MarekOleszczuk said. There are also wall mounted residential use toilets which are relatively new to the market which do have a tank.